# Two Way Serial Communication- Cannot access string read from Serial Reader Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization, arduino, rfid

I declared a twoWaySerialComm object to to configure the port connection. Inside the twoWaySerialComm class I created a thread to read the incoming serial data in a class called 'SerialReader'. How can access the serial data from the main thread 'twoWaySerialComm'?

I had read the incoming serial data into 'hex' string in the 'SerialReader' class inside a while loop. I am able to print the incoming data inside the while loop, But i am unable to access this 'hex' string in the 'twoWaySerialComm' class. Why can't I access the 'hex' string outside the while loop? how can this be done?

```
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.NoSuchPortException;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author asanka
 */
public class TwoWaySerialComm {

    private static TwoWaySerialComm twoWaySerialComm;

    String read;

    private TwoWaySerialComm() throws NoSuchPortException, PortInUseException, UnsupportedCommOperationException, IOException {
        String portName = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
        if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
            System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
        } else {
            CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);

            if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
                SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

                SerialReader reader;
                (new Thread(reader = new SerialReader(in))).start();
                read = reader.readHex();

            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static TwoWaySerialComm getTwoWaySerialComm() throws NoSuchPortException, PortInUseException, UnsupportedCommOperationException, IOException {
        if (twoWaySerialComm == null) {
            twoWaySerialComm = new TwoWaySerialComm();
        }
        return twoWaySerialComm;
    }

    public String data() {
        return read;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static class SerialReader implements Runnable {

        String hex;
        InputStream in;

        public SerialReader(InputStream in) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int len;
            try {
                while ((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {

                    hex = new String(buffer, 0, len).replaceAll("\\s", "");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println(hex);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TwoWaySerialComm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        public String readHex() {
            return hex;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable {

        OutputStream out;

        public SerialWriter(OutputStream out) {
            this.out = out;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                int c = 0;
                while ((c = System.in.read()) > -1) {
                    this.out.write(c);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you're running the read operation in another Thread. When calling the readHex() method, that Thread probably hasn't filled in the hex field yet.

You'll need to call join() on the new Thread first, to ensure it has finished.
Or use the CompletableFuture from the java.util.concurrent package.